# Shadowbox closes safari on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, shadowbox, ipad-2

This happens in iPad and its native Safari browser:

I have 2 pages one opens a shadowbox which loads the second page which has a form in it. Once the user selects some fields from the form and presses the button the form page (in the shadowbox) calls some functions which work perfectly and lastly it calls `parent.closeShadowbox()`, which is a function in the first page which executes the shadowboxes native `Shadowbox.close()`.

When the `Shadowbox.close` is called it closes THE ENTIRE BROWSER, not just the shadowbox.

I've googled, I've searched on the shadowbox's website's forum and nothing.

Anyone have any ideas what's goin on?